# How to make an installation interface for an application written in python

Tags: python

I'm working on an app, it's in the final stages of development, and I want to help design an installation interface for it, can anyone guide me?

Comment: Why don't you use InstallShield or something like that if you alredy 've got an exe

Comment: Which OS is this for?  Different OSs have different requirements.  Some require admin privs to modify some special OS bits, some are just straight copies.

Comment: IMHO, this is rather broad. If users are expected to already have a Python installation, then [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) is probably an option. In that case, installation can be as simple as typing `pip your_app`. If you intend to package the app in an executable file, then there are two question: choosing a tool to package the app into an executable file (pyexe, etc.), and choosing an end user installer (InstallShield, InnoSetup, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question largely depends on how thorough you want your installer to be, since **installing a program** basically translates to **embed this complex piece of software on my pc for me to use hassle-free**. To make a common one click installer, it will be a long process that is explained better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629220/what-does-a-standard-installation-actually-do). I wont get too deep into this because there's many builders and tools that do the heavy lifting and simplify this process significantly. Just an example anyways, these can be built in Visual Studio and are formatted as .msi or .exe, or packaged up as self-extracting in InstallSheild. On a side note mac/linux installations work **very** differently. This is for Windows only!

If you are leaning towards making a much more indie-friendly installer that just moves a file to a location, a simple Windows VB program that is ran with admin privileges would do the trick. Simply fetch some files from a http source to a location on your computer, and VB supports a lot of very nice GUI elements to guide the user through the process.

As ironic as this sounds, you could even make the downloader in python and bundle that as an exe installer. It could utilize PyQT5, or just stay plain-jane command line and spit out the log as it executes.

At the end of the day, a bare-bones method would just be to <s>host your application through a github repo and have clients `git clone`, or</s> add your code to pypi.

Comment: Git clone is indeed very effective for developpers. But I would not advise it for a end user installation...